# Shift button to extreem right of div

Tags: css, html

I have div as below:

```
<div id="divObservationInput" style="height: 55%; vertical-align: text-bottom;" class="sloInputBox">
            <div id="divEnlargeTextarea" style="height: 97%; width: 99%">


                    <textarea onkeyup="txtobservationbox_onTextChanged();return false;" name="txtobservationbox" id="txtobservationbox" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: auto; font-size: 12pt;">@ViewBag.ObserverText</textarea>


            </div>
        </div>
```

And button div as:

```
<div id="DivShowInModal" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);">
    <div>
        <div style="padding-top: 1%; text-align: right; position: relative; width: 80%; height:2%">
            <button onclick="CloseShowInModal()" class="buttoncss">Close</button>
        </div>
        <div id="divModal" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px;">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Its looking:

[image]

I want to shoft that close button to extreem right of div.
i.e. It should be extreem right to textarea.

Please help me.

I tried button setting its right padding to 100%.

But it didnt helped.

Comment: Right padding defined an space between your button and the right border. Remove right padding and try padding-left.
As this is a popin you may use position:fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your '80%' 'width' to '100%' for this 'div'

```
<div style="padding-top: 1%; text-align: right; position: relative; width: 100%; height:2%">
    <button onclick="CloseShowInModal()" class="buttoncss">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to do
in HTML

```
<div class="relative">
    <div class="button">
        <button onclick="CloseShowInModal()" class="buttoncss">Close</button>
    </div>
    <div id="divModal" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px;">
    </div>

</div>
```

In CSS

```
.relative { position: relative; } .button { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code n try once

```
<div id="DivShowInModal" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);">
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div style="padding-top: 1%; text-align: right; position: absolute; width: 80%; height:2%;right:0">
            <button onclick="CloseShowInModal()" class="buttoncss">Close</button>
        </div>
        <div id="divModal" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px;">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

i have scaled it by position:absolute and right:0

Answer (score 1):

You can use position absolute with right 0 for button. For that you need to give position relative for it's parent div.

```
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rj3Mh/)
```